# ng-switch on empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular and I want to check when a string is empty using ng-switch. The following code doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
<div ng-switch on="foo">
    <span ng-switch-when="">This string is empty</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>This string is not empty</span>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular.js ng-switch ---testing if value is empty or undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453689/angular-js-ng-switch-testing-if-value-is-empty-or-undefined)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to include the empty string in your controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['', 'other'];
  $scope.selection = $scope.items[0];
}
```

For additional reference, see the API: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Also, here's a working version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/upPgU/

Answer (score 21):

```
<div ng-switch on="foo || 'null'">
    <span ng-switch-when="null">This string is empty</span>
    <span ng-switch-default>This string is not empty</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thats more helpful

Comment: Instead of `'null'` you can write `''` and then the ng-switch-when works as it was before. So you can use `<div ng-switch="foo || ''"` and then `<span ng-switch-when="">...</span>`

Answer (score 4):

Definite dupe of [Angular.js ng-switch ---testing if value is empty or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453689/angular-js-ng-switch-testing-if-value-is-empty-or-undefined).

The accepted answer isn't ideal there either.  In my oh so humble opinion the most elegant and clear solution has the least upvotes over there.

```
<div ng-switch="!!selection">
   <div ng-switch-when="false">Empty, Null or undefined</div>
   <div ng-switch-when="true">The string is not empty</div>
</div>
```