# How to add a condition in ng-model (keypress) event in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Consider my code snippet:

```
<div ng-app>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <h1>Login as {{myName}}</h1>
</div>
```

Running Demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/renishar/Lt5D5/2/

In the code when you type the username into the text field, it is printed in the h1 tag.

At the moment this produces the output:

> Login user1

when I type `user1` into the text field.

I need to prefix `user1` with the word `as` **only when the user has entered a value**. So if the text box is empty it will show:

> Login

As soon as they enter any value into the text box it should display:

> Login as "value entered in text box"

Comment: It is really not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you mean you need to display 'as' only if `myName` is not empty ?

Comment: when the key event executes the text displayed on h1 with the textbox value

Comment: i need to append 'as ' with the textbox value

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-switch on empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434284/ng-switch-on-empty-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an extra `<span>` which will only be shown when `myName` is not empty.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
<h1>Login <span ng-show="myName">as </span>{{myName}}</h1>
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/8TceS/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-hide when the value is empty

http://jsfiddle.net/Linksonder/u9A7n/

```
  <h1 ng-hide="!myName">Login as {{myName}}</h1>
```