# Angular.js ng-switch ---testing if value is empty or undefined

Tags: angularjs

In Angular.js templating, I need to test if a value is undefined or empty.... I am not sure how to do this since `ng-switch-when` tests for expressions in strings. I needed to use `ng-switch` because it's a if else condition. Any ideas?

```
<div ng-switch="vipLabel">
  <div ng-switch-when="vipLabel.toString()">
    <h1>Getting infomration...one sec</h1>
  </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <h3>Do you wish to unbind {{node.label}} from {{ vipLabel }}?</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ng-switch allows expressions, you can use placeholder, as such:

```
<div ng-switch="selection || '_undefined_'" >      
      <span ng-switch-when="_undefined_">I am set to zero or undefined?!</span>      
      <span ng-switch-default>This string is not empty</span>
</div>
```

For more info: [ng-switch on empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434284/ng-switch-on-empty-string)

You usually do it within controller(see answer#1 in linked thread).

Answer (score 20):

```html
<div ng-switch="!!selection">
   <div ng-switch-when="false">Empty, Null or undefined</div>
   <div ng-switch-when="true">The string is not empty</div>
</div>
```

Comment: easily the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

Following solution would also work (using angular 1.3.10):

```
<div ng-switch="selection">
    <div ng-switch-default>The string is not empty!</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="undefined">The string is empty!</div>
</div>
```